# Python/With selenium, trying to express a xpath for a color so all buttons matching the color can be clicked

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm currently working with Selenium and Python to create a script that helps with booking free spots on a website for internships so you don't have to check it all the time.

So I'm trying to express an xpath for a color which is used in a data cell element to mark any available spots. In the end I want to use this xpath in selenium so it can be clicked.
Now I got the problem that I can't locate the color in the HTML source. I used the "color digital meter" in apple to find out the color(please see the picture attached) but can't locate the element in the HMTL. I also searched most of the HTML code by hand. Am I missing something?
Thanks in advance!
[Screenshot of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTyED.png)

Link to HTML Code: http://filedropper.com/FRGJDgha

```
browser.get('https://www.pj-portal.de/index_hro.php?PAGE_ID=101')

delay = 2

browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(text(),'1/')]")
print("found")
Liste1 = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts with(text(),'1/')]")
print(len(Liste1))
```

I tried it with a xpath targeting a text attribute that shows the available spots and the total spots but I figure targeting the green color would be the neater solution.

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML and your code trials.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I can't specify the relevant HTML part because I can't locate where the color has been implemented, thats why i included the whole HTML. I know its a pain to look at but I thought someone has an idea what to search for.

Comment: HTML code link is broken

Comment: @Dev updated it, maybe you got an idea. Thanks for looking at it !

Comment: You can add html code as part of this post instead link, it is bound to break at some point.

Comment: Yeah I tried that but the code is too long  and since I don’t know in which section to find it I posted the filedropper link